# KPfonts small caps italic

Tags: fonts, small-caps, italic, kpfonts

I don't seem to make `kpfonts` work with small caps italic text. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\newcommand*{\mytext}{Testing 1 2 3 testing!}

\begin{document}
  \textsc{\itshape\mytext} % this doesn't work

  \textit{\scshape\mytext} % this doesn't either
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use one of the following forms to get the slanted smallcaps font of the `kpfonts` package:

```
\textscsl{Testing 1 2 3 testing!}
{\scslshape Testing 1 2 3 testing!}
```

*Addendum* (Thanks, @egreg!): Alternatively, you could load the `kpfonts` package with the option `easyscsl` and then use the commands `\textsc` (or `\scshape`) and `\textit` (or `\itshape`) in a nested fashion:

```
\textsc{\textit{Testing 1 2 3 testing!}}
{\scshape\itshape Testing 1 2 3 testing!}
```

For more on this, see p. 5 of the package's user guide.

Comment: The `easyscsl` makes it possible to nest `\textsl` and `\textsc` (or conversely). I'm not sure about `\textit`.

Comment: @egreg - thanks for this suggestion. I've incorporated it in an addendum.